# Multithreaded Program Gets Interrupted with "Alarm Clock"

Tags: c++, pthreads, signals, libcurl

All, my multithreaded program keeps getting interrupted and "Alarm clock" is being written to console.

After some googling, many people mention this is related to "sleep," but none of my threads are calling sleep.  The current process is

1. Pass a function and parameters to a starter function
2. Starter function starts `n` threads and passes function from (1) and proper parameters to each thread
3. Each thread runs function with the parameters it was given, each function is independent only relying on parameters and local memory.
4. Starter function joins each created thread `pthread_join(cur_thread[i], 0)`

I've been trying to use `strace` and `gdb` to figure out whats throwing the signal. `gdb` just says "No stack" and `strace` doesn't stop at all... I'm thinking I'm about to over write the SIGALRM signal handler...

I'm out of ideas, could anyone offer any suggestions?

**New information**: This seems to be related to libcurl. I use it to get mjpegs from the network. If I do not use libcurl, the SIGALRM does not fire. My libcurl code is as follows:

```
static void * capture_function(void * cam)
{
    MyData * camera = (MyData *)cam;

    //Create the curl
    camera->m_curl = curl_easy_init();

    //Connect to the camera
    curl_easy_setopt(camera->m_curl, CURLOPT_URL, camera->m_ip);

    //Set up our callback functions
    curl_easy_setopt(camera->m_curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, CurlWriteCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(camera->m_curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)camera);
    curl_easy_perform(camera->m_curl);

    camera->m_state = camera->m_state & ~CAPTURING; //Remove the capturing flag;
    curl_easy_cleanup(camera->m_curl);

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Sample code and output vs expected output???  You outlined it well, but with threading in particular, it is nuances in implementation that causes issues.

Comment: I supplied some implementaton code, the program is pretty robust at this current state ... Please inform me if I should supply more.

Comment: Note that this only occurs on the convolution functions after a long amount of computation. The convolution functions can take around 7 SECONDS of extremely heavy computation, which turns into 2800 seconds for `thread_join`

Comment: Does your code call any non-system/libc function not under your command?

Comment: @alk I am fairly confident that other than malloc/free I do not... I am compiling with `-pthread` ... I haven't included the flag in the linking stage though, I feel like the `-pthread` at compile is enough?

Comment: As this looks like image processing:you use which libraries?

Comment: @alk I have written my own analysis functions (requirement). I also have implementations that use OpenCV. They are compiled as separate executables, they do not throw any errors (they also run extremely faster than mine... obviously)

Comment: @alk It seems this is related to libcurl. However, the weird part is I thought I cleaned up libcurl before I start processing...

Comment: Have you tried `CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL`?

Comment: Yep that's exactly what I used. I'm wondering what function could be throwing SIGALRM though after the socket is closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was related to `libcurl`. I had to use

```
 setopt(handle, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
```